# You really don't want to find out

Tags: riddle

> Leave me alone and I will sleep forever
>
> Wake me up rudely and I will rock you with a jab
>
> You will be little hard of hearing but you will thank me forever!

**Who am I?**

Comment: Are any of the answers close to what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes Indeed. Just waiting a little. Couple of very surprising ones with good fit

Comment: Okay, the accepted answer makes more sense than mine. Lol I would, however, propose the change of "Who am I" to "What am I" given the intended answer. Nice one!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you

> an airbag?

As for the title and clues,

> You really don’t want to set off your car’s airbag. An airbag will only go off in a collision (rude awakening), it will hit (jab) you hard, it makes a loud bang, and it saves your life.

Comment: Good one. Do we really need to wake them up(in case of an emergency)? As they are supposed to be automatic. Right?

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like it could be a

> Smoke detector (though if this is it, then other things like a carbon monoxide alarm would also fit)

Leave me alone and I will sleep forever

> If no smoke appears then it will never go off

Wake me up rudely and I will rock you with a jab

> When it goes off your body gets shot with a bit of adrenaline. Like a jab to your nerves

You will be little hard of hearing but you will thank me forever!

> Normally the sound is loud and piercing, it hurts your ears, but it tells you that there is a fire and to get out of a building. It can save your life, so you'd thank it forever.

Comment: It is a good fit Paige. However many times I test the smoke detectors to make sure they are working. During tests they do make noise.

Comment: Testing isn't really leaving it alone, is it?

Comment: Yeah. But smoke alarms don't stay quiet. When the battery runs out they start chirping. That is not sleeping forever when left alone

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is a silly answer, but are you:

> The Hulk

**Explanation**

```
Leave me alone and I will sleep forever
```

> When Bruce Banner is not made angry or is left alone, the Hulk could stay "asleep" forever.

```
Wake me up rudely and I will rock you with a jab
```

> Any time Bruce is made angry and turns into the Hulk, the Hulk usually punches the first thing he sees.

```
You will be little hard of hearing but you will thank me forever!
```

> **EDIT** My answer is no longer applicable with the new wording but was based on the previous wording *"Little hard of hearing but you will thank me forever!"* And my explanation was *"The Hulk doesn't really listen to orders, but he's a crucial part of the Avengers (or Thor's team in the latest movie) and is to be greatly thanked for his reckless heroism."*

```
Who am I?
```

> The Hulk

And to address the title:

> You really don't want to wake the Hulk up. *"You wouldn't like me when I'm angry"* You REALLY don't want to find out.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. My answer is very different Hawkeye

Comment: @DEEM LOL! Yeah, I didn't think this would be it. But it seemed to fit so well. I think all the Marvel fans will appreciate my effort though. Lol. I had to try. I'll keep chewing on it. =D

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

> earphones/headphones

Leave me alone and I will sleep forever

> Well they don't do anything if they are never used

Wake me up rudely and I will rock you with a jab

> If you plug them in when the volume is turned up high, they kind of give you a "jab" of a burst of sound

You will be little hard of hearing but you will thank me forever!

> Earphones do make you a little hard of hearing if you use them too much but they are very helpful in life and they can be useful in many situations

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> Seat/safety belts of an automobile

As,

> Seat/safety belts can be kept in an un-applied condition and they can lie like that forever
>  When brakes are applied in a speeding vehicle, seat belts come into action rudely with a small thud/impact but we thank them ever for their intended purpose.

Comment: Hard of hearing?

Comment: Hard of hearing - can be interpreted as - they work quietly and it's hard on wearer's part to hear it clearly, perhaps:-)

Answer (score 0):

> **is it a human talking to (or about) their alarm clock?**

leave me alone and I will sleep for ever

> human will sleep

wake me up rudely and I will...

> human turns alarm clock off when they wake up

you will be a little hard of hearing...

> alarm clocks are loud but necessary